# C++ setlocale() returns "NULL"

Tags: docker, setlocale

I try to run my program in a docker container which is based on `alpine:3.8` with `locale` I installed. I can get locale result correctly but in my program, I use `setlocale()` function to read and transform some unicodes but got `NULL` result. The weird thing is that the program works well in local server(**CentOS**).

I installed locale in alpine by this

```
https://github.com/rilian-la-te/musl-locales
```

which works well, I got the correct locale/locale -a /locale -m results.

The codes are as below:

```
fprintf(stderr, "setlocale: \"%s\"\n", setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "zh_CN.UTF-8"));                       
setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN.UTF-8");
```

I expect the output of `zh_CN.UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

Use `locale -a` to check available locales on your system.
You should only use supported UTF-8 locale on your system. I assume in this case you may need to change "zh_CN.UTF-8" to "C.UTF-8" for better chance of portability ("C.UTF-8" is POSIX standards-compliant default locale).